# Scroll in the top and open a new page with anchor

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I have this code in my site with anchor jquery pages, this code scroll in the top but dont open a new page when i click the text button

code js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    //Click event to scroll to top
    $('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
        return false;
    });
```

code html, text button:

```
<a href="<?php $url->_getURL1('openpage'); ?>" class="scrollToTop">Domestic Electrical installation</a>
<a href="<?php $url->_getURL2('openpage'); ?>" class="scrollToTop">Comercial Electrical installation</a>
```

thank you for your help

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: and your question is ?

Comment: @ray9209 and bipen , i edit the question. tnx

Comment: So when you click the link you want the page to scroll to the top and open the link in a new window? but it is currently only scrolling to the top and not opening the link in a new window?

Comment: so when either link is clicked, you want the page to scroll up?

Comment: @ ray9209 when click the link i want the page to scroll to the top and open the link in a new window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the link to open in a new window you will have to set the `target` attribute to `_blank`

```html
<a href="<?php $url->_getURL1('openpage'); ?>" class="scrollToTop" target="_blank">Domestic Electrical installation</a>
<a href="<?php $url->_getURL2('openpage'); ?>" class="scrollToTop" target="_blank">Comercial Electrical installation</a>
```

and in your click listener you will want to return `true` so it does not prevent the default behavior

```js
$('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the return false;

```
 $('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
    //return false; This prevents the normal action of the anchor
});
```

Maybe add target="_blank" to your links so they will open in a new tab

```
<a href="<?php $url->_getURL1('openpage'); ?>" class="scrollToTop" target="_blank">Domestic Electrical installation</a>
```